# How can I dIsplay data titles from a url link to tableview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a url `http://percipi.org/announce?sno=1&lim=1000`. According this data structure I want to display the "id", "text" and "date" from the data into tableview cell. By creating mdalobject I can got the object of text in console, but I am unable to display the data in tableview. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to just "post teh codez", because that's not really possible for such a vague question. But take a look at the [AFNetworking](http://engineering.gowalla.com/2011/10/24/afnetworking/) library.

It'll let you make a request to that JSON feed and will probably return an NSArray of NSDictionaries. From there you can keep a reference to that NSArray and use it to populate your table view.
There are many many tutorials on the net on exactly this. Pretty much any tutorial on UITableView should be able to help you with the rest.